# How to create Label with Chinese and Japanese characters with custom color

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use cocos2d-x (c++) ver. 3.8 on tvOS (Apple TV)

I don't want to use TTF versions because I don't have decent Arial TTF font which includes Chinese and Japanese characters and yet has acceptable file size (up to 1MB).

If I use the `Label::createWithSystemFont()` this doesn't allow to change the text color. At least I did not find it how to change it.

```
auto *n =  Label::createWithSystemFont("洗牌位置", font, fontSize, dimensions, hAlignment, vAlignment);
n->setColor(Color3B::RED);
n->setTextColor(Color4B::RED);
```

This produces black text...

**EDIT:**

In a desperate situation I've tried something you might think I'm mad.
But it doesn't work neither. The result is still black. Would you know ANY way how to change the color of the Label??

```
Node* NodeFactory::colorizeLabel (Label *lbl, const Color3B& color)
{
     auto *maskSprite = lbl;

    CCRenderTexture * rt;
        rt = CCRenderTexture::create(
                                     maskSprite->getContentSize().width*maskSprite->getScaleX(),
                                     maskSprite->getContentSize().height*maskSprite->getScaleY()
                                     , kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
        );
        maskSprite->setPosition(ccp(
                                    (maskSprite->getContentSize().width*maskSprite->getScaleX())/2,
                                    (maskSprite->getContentSize().height*maskSprite->getScaleY())/2
                                    )
                                );


    //rt->begin();
    rt->beginWithClear(120, 120, 0, 0);
    ((Node*)maskSprite)->visit();
    rt->end();

    Sprite *retval = Sprite::createWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
    retval->setColor(Color3B::WHITE);
    //retval->setBlendFunc((ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE });

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: upvoted the question as it is perfectly valid IMO, but would downvote the avatar if I could because of the shameless advertising :-)
on topic: did you test that the same code results in colored output with a TTF and using ASCII characters? see no reason why it should not be possible to change color when a system font is involved.

Comment: yes, TTF works fine. Somewhere there is a note that color change is disabled for system font because it should be completely system (incl.color). Now, I'm in search for decent TTF font :-(

Comment: Looks like the fix for the known issue "Label: stroke color of system font is incorrect on iOS" exists for no earlier than cocos2d-x-4.0alpha...

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/11112 I've tried to patch it but can not find the corresponding diff. Can you see it? I only found this "info.strokeColorA" which is correct in my version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND solution for colored system font on tvOS:
FIX: CCDevice-tvos.mm:

ORIG:

```
[str drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle }];
```

NEW:

```
[str drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:info->tintColorR green:info->tintColorG blue:info->tintColorB alpha:info->tintColorA]
}];
```